# Calling the custom annotation class into viewForAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How do i call the CustomAnnotation class into the viewforannotation? As it looks now, it will just crash, when tapping the annotation.

```
class CustomAnnotation: MKPinAnnotationView, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var annotationData : [Apartments] = []

var fishAnnoTitle : String!
var fishAnnoImage : NSData!

let selectedLabel : UILabel = UILabel.init(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 38))
let selectedImage : UIImageView = UIImageView.init(frame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 300, 200))

var selectedButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton!

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(false, animated: animated)

    if(selected)
    {

        selectedLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        selectedLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        selectedLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "Trebuchet MS", size: 20)
        selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        selectedLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        selectedLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
        selectedLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        selectedLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

        selectedImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        selectedImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
        selectedImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

        selectedButton.frame = CGRectMake(262, 0, 38, 38)
        selectedButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        selectedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "advance.png"), forState: .Normal)
        selectedButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Apartments")
        let fetchResults = try! context.executeFetchRequest(freq) as! [Apartments]

        self.annotationData = fetchResults
        let countImages = self.annotationData.count

        if countImages != 0 {
            for row in 0...countImages-1 {
                let dataImage : Apartments = self.annotationData[row]
                self.fishAnnoImage = (dataImage.valueForKey("lejlighedBillede") as? NSData)!
                self.fishAnnoTitle = "\(dataImage.valueForKey("lejlighedHusleje")!)"

                selectedImage.image = UIImage(data: dataImage.lejlighedBillede!)
                self.addSubview(selectedImage)

                selectedLabel.text = self.fishAnnoTitle!
                self.addSubview(selectedLabel)

                self.addSubview(selectedButton)

            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        selectedLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        selectedImage.removeFromSuperview()
        selectedButton.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
}
```

And now i want to use the custom class, so i can make a custom annotation.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("CustomAnnotation") as CustomAnnotation
        annotationView = CustomAnnotation(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "CustomAnnotation")

        return annotationView

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to make it normal annotation instead of your custom? that does not make any sense you need to dequeue it as your annotation

```
var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("CustomAnnotation") as CustomAnnotation!
```

and custom Annotation needs to conform `MKAnnotation`

Comment: When I use that line of code it will crash and tells me "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: what is nil? annotationView? mapView? i cannot debug for you

Comment: Exactly that line of code i bugging. I have to make as! CustomAnnotation

Comment: check that https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html and look at my edit, your custom annotation is not annotation at all

Comment: I assume that conforming MKAnnotationView in the Custom Annotation is enough?

Comment: yes, that makes your custom annotation, usable annotation